# How to play a 3d video properly?

Tags: 11.10, hd-video

I have a video in mkv format that shows two identical separate videos together, and not one over the other in vlc. On windows, I am able to play it adjusting deep, 3d mode (red cyan, with 3d TV and its glasses thorugh hdmi), etc.
Bino does not work at all. I can only select rec cyan and it crashes on full screen. I am using ubuntu 11.10 with fully 3d support.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your MKV file uses [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_Video_Coding) encoding, which is a special mode of H264. As of 2016 there is no pure linux solution for amd64/x86 platform (the wikipedia article lists software for Windows/Wine).
If you own a RaspberryPi you can use [omxplayer](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer), which is capable of decoding MVC.

Answer (score -1):

Normally an anaglyph (3D via red/blue glasses) video has to be a single file containing both color filters. You could use a video editor (there are many open source video editors available for Linux) to combine your two video files and export to a single anaglyph video file.